# How to insert a value into a table when creating another one

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table "utilizadores" with the fields "id / nome_utilizador / pin / data_criação / saldo"

[table "utilizadores"][image: 1]

And I have a procedure "criar conta" where the user fill the fields from the table "utilizadores" except the field "saldo"

[Procedure "criar conta"][image: 2]

So, what I want is when i run the procedure, the field "saldo" from table "utilizadores", updates automatically with 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a default value for a field, and if the INSERT statement does not contain the field, it will put the default value in the field.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  namo VARCHAR(100),
  saldo INT DEFAULT 1000
);

INSERT INTO t1 (namo) VALUES ('Rick')

INSERT INTO t1 (namo,saldo) VALUES ('Bob',300)

SELECT * FROM t1
```

would show

```
namo: Rick      saldo: 1000
namo: Bob       saldo: 300
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

- welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: How to do it with a date?

Comment: It looks like you can only put the current timestamp ( DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) or null as a default value https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html